# Extract a dictionary from <key><val>...<key><val> wiredata

Tags: python

I'm extending a low level emulator written in C, where I have to send and receive a number of socket telegrams. Rather than messing around with this in C, I'm making this extension in an embedded python script. This part is simple enough, but as I'm not exactly a skilled python coder, I tend to end up with some rather in-elegant code. For instance, parsing a part of the wire encoded dictionary.

On the wire, the dictionary looks like this:

<3><Mkey3><456><Mkey2><Mval2><MKey1><MVal1>

Mening that there are 3 key-value pairs: {MKey3: 456, MKey2: MVal2, MKey1: MVal1}

I've ended up with this implementation, that works good enough for the purpose of testing, but I'm curious as to how much simpler it could be?

```
    tiddata = '<3><Mkey3><456><Mkey2><Mval2><MKey1><MVal1>'
    q1 = re.compile('^\<(?P<idatacnt>[^\>]*)\>(?P<idataload>.*)$')
    m1 = q1.search(tiddata)
    r1 = m1.groupdict()

    tidload = r1['idataload']
    tidcnt = int(r1['idatacnt'])

    tidata = {}
    q2 = re.compile ('\<(?P<k>[^\>]*)\>\<(?P<v>[^\>]*)\>')
    for m in q2.finditer(tidload):
        t = m.groupdict()
        tidata[t['k']] = t['v']

    if len(tidata) != tidcnt:
        print('Invalid itemdata: <%s>' %tiddata)
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
tiddata = '<Mkey3><456><Mkey2><Mval2><MKey1><MVal1>'
t = tiddata.strip('<>').split('><')
output = {t[i]: t[i+1] for i in range(0, len(t), 2)}
```